# Generate footer for all PDF pages with CakePDF and the DomPDF engine

Tags: dompdf

I'm trying to use CakePDF, a CakePHP plugin for PDF generation, and I've chosen DomPDF as the PDF render engine.

So far the resulting PDFs are pretty good, but I can't put footers on each page of the PDF. I've read through the almost inexistant CakePDF documentation and there s no example or reference to this feature.

I've tried to set the footer on the CakePdf options but it doesn't seem to work

```
        $this->pdfConfig = array(
        'download' => false,
        'filename' => 'foo.pdf',
        'margin' => array(
            'bottom' => 5,
            'left' => 10,
            'right' => 10,
            'top' => 45
        ),
        'options' => array(
            'footer-html'=>Router::url('/', true).'View/Pdf/pdf_footer.ctp'
            )
    );
```

I also tried to simply put a div on the PDF view, but it only shows on the first page:

```
  <body>
    <div id="page-wrap" class="pdf">
    <div style="text-align: center; position: fixed; width: 100%; bottom:5px;">Footer text here</div>
<!-- insert pdf code here -->
</body>
```

Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without delving into the code to much it's difficult to see how CakePDF supports headers/footers using the options. The documentation indicates that the optional features vary by engine. More than likely what you're trying is specific to one of the other engines.

As far as the HTML+CSS footer goes, what you're experiencing is just a quirk of how dompdf processes document. dompdf basically adds page-static content (e.g. fixed-position elements) starting with the page where they're encountered. Headers/footers should be at the top of the document (the first elements inside the body element) in order to appear on all pages.

Comment: (This is something that might change in a future release.)